# Examples of pointwise convergence not implying $L_2$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

I'm looking for simple, easy examples for the following two phenomena where there is no need to consider the convergence of any subsequences. I'm considering sequences $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset L_2([-\pi,\pi],m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

1. Pointwise convergence does not imply $L_2$ convergence.
2. $L_2$ convergence does not imply pointwise convergence.

I see that any example for 2. would also be an example highlighting that $L_2$ convergence does not imply uniform convergence. I already have a proof for the fact that uniform convergence implies $L_2$ convergence, and whilst I have some examples for showing that pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence I am finding it hard to adapt them for these two cases here.

Comment: 1) $f_n =n \chi_{(0,1/n)}$ 2) typewriter sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a standard example for 2). Divide $[-\pi,\pi]$ into two equal sub-intervals $I_{1,1}$ and $I_{1,2}$; the divide these again into equal sub-intervals $I_{2,1},I_{2,2},I_{2,3},I_{2,4}$, and so on. If you arrange the characteristic functions of  all these intervals in a single sequence you get an example for 2). For 1) you can use the example given in above comment.

Comment: Is the example you have given for 2). somewhat similar to the one given in the comments? Namely, the typewriter sequence? Similar in that you get an, infinite sequence of 0's and 1's so that you can't have pointwise convergence?